# Can't get my wordpress widget to overflow properly

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, visual-glitch

I'm having difficulty trying to clip the overflow of text in a 'Recent Posts' widget on my wordpress.

The wordpress in question is [an event planning blog](http://blog.orionmixology.com) : the theme is 'Interior Set5'

As you can see the 'Recent posts', and all widgets for that matter can't overflow properly.
This leaves them looking cluttered and isn't what I hope the end result will look like.

So far I have not been able to find the code that relates to it tto edit it by hand.
I've found what I believe to be the area of code in the editor, but when i changed the overflow value it did nothing, and when I erased the section of code as a whole it made no visible change to widgets at all.

If any knows how to tidy up that recent post section I'd really appreciate it.

Best

Francis

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow-x:hidden to the following:

```
#sidebar ul li {
    background: url("images/bullet.gif") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #4F4F4F;
    font: 12px Arial;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This is located under http://blog.orionmixology.com/wp-content/themes/Interior-set5/style.css on line 795. This will at least hide it, if that's what you want.

I'd suggest changing the height of the a tag, and just positioning the background image accordingly though.